# Eliminating special characters in dataframe rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe (sour):

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{\"OV188\"}>" 0.628465804066543
"2" "<{\"OV191\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"3" "<{\"OV194\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"4" "<{\"OV195\"}>" 0.680221811460259
"5" "<{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"6" "<{\"OV200\"}>" 0.56007393715342
"7" "<{\"OV188\"},{\"OV200\"}>" 0.56007393715342
"8" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"9" "<{\"OV194\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"10" "<{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"11" "<{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"12" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"13" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"14" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV197\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"15" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV195\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"16" "<{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"17" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"}>" 0.584103512014787
"18" "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"}>" 0.584103512014787
```

The required result is the following format:

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{OV188}>" 0.628465804066543
"2" "<{OV191}>" 0.584103512014787
"3" "<{OV194}>" 0.584103512014787
"4" "<{OV195}>" 0.680221811460259
"5" "<{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"6" "<{OV200}>" 0.56007393715342
"7" "<{OV188},{OV200}>" 0.56007393715342
"8" "<{OV191},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"9" "<{OV194},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"10" "<{OV195},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"11" "<{OV194},{OV195},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"12" "<{OV191},{OV195},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"13" "<{OV191},{OV194},{OV195},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"14" "<{OV191},{OV194},{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"15" "<{OV191},{OV195}>" 0.584103512014787
"16" "<{OV194},{OV195}>" 0.584103512014787
"17" "<{OV191},{OV194},{OV195}>" 0.584103512014787
"18" "<{OV191},{OV194}>" 0.584103512014787
```

I use the following code for it:

```
a<-sour
names(a) <- sub("X\\.(.*)\\.", "\\1",  names(a))
a$sequence <- sub('<\\{"(.*)"\\}>', "<{\\1}>", a$sequence)
sour<-a
```

However, I still get unwanted characters in case there are more than one value at "sequence" column as seen here (from line 7 and on):

```
"sequence" "support"
"1" "<{OV188}>" 0.628465804066543
"2" "<{OV191}>" 0.584103512014787
"3" "<{OV194}>" 0.584103512014787
"4" "<{OV195}>" 0.680221811460259
"5" "<{OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"6" "<{OV200}>" 0.56007393715342
"7" "<{OV188\"},{\"OV200}>" 0.56007393715342
"8" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"9" "<{OV194\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"10" "<{OV195\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"11" "<{OV194\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"12" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"13" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"14" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV197}>" 0.584103512014787
"15" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV195}>" 0.584103512014787
"16" "<{OV194\"},{\"OV195}>" 0.584103512014787
"17" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195}>" 0.584103512014787
"18" "<{OV191\"},{\"OV194}>" 0.584103512014787
```

What do I have to change in the code in order that line 7 to 18 will be without quotation marks and slashes as in lines 1-6?

```
> dput (sour)
structure(list(sequence = c("<{\"OV188\"}>", "<{\"OV191\"}>", 
"<{\"OV194\"}>", "<{\"OV195\"}>", "<{\"OV197\"}>", "<{\"OV200\"}>", 
"<{\"OV188\"},{\"OV200\"}>", "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV197\"}>", "<{\"OV194\"},{\"OV197\"}>", 
"<{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>", "<{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>", 
"<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>", "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"},{\"OV197\"}>", 
"<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV197\"}>", "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV195\"}>", 
"<{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"}>", "<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"},{\"OV195\"}>", 
"<{\"OV191\"},{\"OV194\"}>"), support = c(0.628465804066543, 
0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 0.680221811460259, 0.584103512014787, 
0.56007393715342, 0.56007393715342, 0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 
0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 
0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 0.584103512014787, 
0.584103512014787)), .Names = c("sequence", "support"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```

Comment: Please post a `dput` of your data.

Comment: @SabDeM, I added the dput of the sour. at the end of the question.

Comment: it does not have the `\` nor the `/`, i mean the `dput`.

Comment: It has the \"OV188\" for each character and I would like to remove them as seen in the example.

Comment: If you are just trying to remove the backslashes, you don't have to, they aren't really there. It's like the kid in the Matrix that bends the spoon, you just have to realize that there is no spoon.

Comment: I would like to get an output as seen in the example. Without the special characters.

Comment: I have a code that needs the result format as an input in order to work.

Comment: If you what output without escaped interior quote characters, then use `cat`. I repeat Pierre's comment.... there is no spoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

sour %>%
  mutate(sequence = 
           sequence %>% 
           stri_replace_all_fixed('"', '') %>%
           shQuote(type = "cmd"))
```

I would also recommend unnesting sequence.

```
library(tidyr)

sour %>%
  mutate(sequence = sequence %>% stri_split_fixed(",")) %>%
  unnest(sequence) %>%
  mutate(sequence = sequence %>% extract_numeric)
```

Comment: It appeared the removing the double-quotes was not the questioners goal. He just didn't realize that there were no backslashes.

Comment: Thanks @bramtayl, The solution is very nice but please find the required result there is an outer quotation which are eliminated by your solution. I need for example  "1" "<{OV188}>" and by your solution I get 1 <{OV188}>

Comment: I suppose you can just add back in literal quotations around the edges. See edit.

Comment: @bramtayl, Thanks a lot!